# Show git name when in submodules

Tags: oh-my-zsh

Do you know how to show the git name in git plugin?

It would be nice to be able to see the name of current git repo, when in a submodule. Now I am unable to know if I am in the parent git repo or in a submodule.

I tried to rename the folder containing the submodule to *.git, but then oh-my-zsh stoped showing the branch.

Thanks